# System i SQL is tinyint supported?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Can't see any reference to tinyint by System i online resources itjungle.com, I am wondering if it is possible to use it? There was reference to it on IBM and midrange.com but that didn't really help :

[IBM say support for tinyint being ported](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cli/rzadpwhatsnew.htm)

[midrange.com forum post indicates tinyint not part of ANSI standards](http://archive.midrange.com/midrange-l/201303/msg00949.html)

Comment: Have you tried to create a table with a tinyint column?

Comment: Yes, using interactive sql, the following message is displayed: TINYINT in *LIBL type *SQLUDT not found.

Comment: FWiW: Re the "ported" doc reference, to save anyone actually having to visit the page, the drill-down is "Database->Reference->SQL Call Level Interface" and the specific text is: "Support for TINYINT data type. CLI applications being ported from other platforms that bind TINYINT types as application data types will now run on IBM i."; i.e. that doc reference is solely for the use of the SQL CLI, not for the use of the DB2 for i SQL more generally, for which, if such support ever were added, a similar "What's new" would be found under Database->Reference->SQL Reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'tinyint' is not supported in DB2 for i.

[This documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzpdf.pdf) (IBM i 7.3) on **page 96** tells you the available types and you should see that Small Integer is the smallest available numeric type.

You can see also the available numeric types [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_numericdatatypes.html). Although this link take you to z/OS documentation, the same rules apply.